# Change the temp directory for a user with Microsoft Word 2000

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I have a project with a very strange architecture: several Microsoft Word are creating documents based on copy/paste of Excel graphs.

Each Word is running with its specific account at the same time.

The problem is that the copy/paste produces tmp and *.wmf files in c:\winnt\temp for all accounts.

Is there a way to specify Word and Excel to always use the account's temp directory and not the global Winnt\Temp?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the TEMP and TMP variable for each Windows User is **not** pointing to C:\Winnit\Temp? Many IT teams set it to a single location like C:\Windows\TEMP to make it easier for them to clean the folder as and when necessary. If it is so, then all you need to do is change that to the std temp folder location in userprofile.

Comment: is it possible to check that without connecting with that account ?

Comment: the TEMP and TMP are set to %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Temp

Comment: @Fredv is the creation task does by the Word lauched by the user or by a service?

Comment: by a service created on a specific user (different for each word) (created in OLE)

Comment: @Fredv For any service running under "LocalSystem", the TEMP is set to be "C:\Windows\TEMP". You would need to programmatically change the TEMP Environment variable whenever you execute a task for a specific user and then revert to the default C:\Windows\TEMP.

Comment: The Service is not running under LocalSystem  .. it is launched with its own user which has TEMP and TMP defined in %USERPROFILE%

Comment: @Fredv How can the same service be launched with different credentials? Then it is not a service but a console application.

Comment: We have 8 users and 8 different services. Users : User1, User2, etc   For each account there is a specific service : service1 , service2 , etc each service is launched by its user

Comment: @Fredv In case you have access to service's code, can you log the path pointed by TEMP and TMP environment variable inside the service. This way we can be absolutely sure that Word is ignoring the TEMP path from the user profile.